# open application silently in the background using Shellexecute

Tags: shellexecute, mql5, metatrader5

I have tried the following:

```
#import "shell32.dll" 
int ShellExecuteW(int hwnd,string operation,string file,string parameters,string directory,int showCmd); 
#import
string strParameters = "/c python c:\\createFiles.py ";
int result = ShellExecuteW(0, "open", "cmd.exe", strParameters, NULL, 1);
if (result <= 32) Print("Shell Execute Failed: ", result);
```

The above command is creating the command prompt to open and then execute the respective commands on it. Meanwhile if I am clicking on something and suddenly the execution occurs then the complete windows is hanged and nothing is executed till I reclick outside the cmd prompt.

Kindly, let me know how I can run the command silently without opening the cmd prompt on the screen.